# Firefox drop down selections

Tags: firefox, google-search

Sometimes when I search at google, the auto-suggested search 
queries are selected in a random order. The drop down will 
appear, but when I hit the down arrow, something random like 
the 3rd item is selected, instead of the first.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any idea how to stop it?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: i can only ask programming questions?

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers" from the FAQ about acceptable questions...

Comment: The seems to be more of a "Computer Enthusiast" question than one specific to programming. You may have better luck over on the Super User stack exchange site.

Comment: ok, thanks. Considering firefox and google are the #1 and #2 development tools I use, I figured Id be fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution is restart Firefox.

If you use ***Ubuntu*** with ***Compiz Settings Manager*** :
enable ***Firefox menu fix*** option in ***Workaround*** section.

Read full study on the bug:
[Bug 638386:

Menus show but close on hover with compiz after returning from gnome-screensaver lock](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638386)